# Where can I get Mdbg?

Tags: .net, debugging, mdbg

I'd like to be able to debug .net code using Mdbg. Is there any way of getting it besides installing Visual Studio ( assuming this is a valid way of obtaining ) ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Mdbg  - The .NET Framework Command-Line Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229861.aspx) comes installed with the Windows SDK [7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)|[10](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) as well as Visual Studio.

It's now available on [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MDbg/0.1.0) too.

There is also the [CLR Managed Debugger Sample](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2282) which is a sample program that demonstrates how to build a command line debugger using .net.

<strike>Note that this is source code and does not come with pre-built binaries so you will have have the .net SDK or visual studio installed to be able to build it first.</strike> (It does now include prebuilt binaries in the bin/release folder after you've unzipped it)

Answer (score 5):

Version 4 (for .NET 4.0) can be downloaded from

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=2282

Answer (score 3):

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MDbg/ is another location. Seems to be CLR 4 and has more options for the catch command then the Version 4

Answer (score 0):

The official Microsoft links provided here no longer work.

Luckily, someone downloaded the source while it was still available and made a GitHub repo:
https://github.com/ichengzi/MDbg-Sample