# C# find what the last interacted with instance in the call stack is

Tags: c#, pointers, callstack, cil, stack-frame

I am working on a personal `C#` project where I want to redirect console streams to different inputs/outputs for different object instances. So for example I have a class `User` that I do not have source access to. I have multiple instances of `User`, and I would like to separate the console I/O of the Users (like for instance 1 and 2, output it in the console and for users 2 and 3, write to a file).

For example, `User` calls `Console.WriteLine`. I already figured out how to hook that call at runtime using some dangerous IL manipulation. But now I am stuck: how would I find out what was the User instance that called `Console.WriteLine`?

- I cannot use a field like UID or Name, since the technique should also work on other objects that use `Console.WriteLine`
- It needs to be done at runtime (also no altering of the assembly that contains `User`).
- I have no source access to `User`
- I have no issues with using `unsafe` or in other ways dangerous code

To my understanding, the object reference needs to be stored on the stack as the first parameter to the last frame, but I do not know how I get a pointer to the reference (nor to the last frame). But the information needs to exist somewhere, since the program needs to deconstruct the frame after it leaves the function, right? I kind of remember that whenever a new frame is pushed onto the stack, at the end of the stack before the new frame is added it puts a frame pointer that points to the top of the frame, so If I get to the top of the current frame using the current frame pointer and then read the last frame pointer before it, then go to there and find the parameter I could get the reference, right?

**My Question:**
How would I "climb up" the stack in practice? Is there any other way to get the reference?

(And yes, I know doing this was not intended nor is it good practice, but I really enjoy exactly this aspect of programming.)

Comment: The exact details of how you would do this will be platform-specific, but you're right that if a non-static class method calls `Console.WriteLine`, then that method will have access to its `this` pointer. That is typically held in a caller-preserved register, so it should not be hard to get at in your hook from asm, but the details...

Comment: Related: [How do I get the executing object for a stackframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/889310).  The consensus there was that it's impossible using .NET code, but might be possible using assembly code.  On the other hand [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75297) by Lars Truijens to [Obtain parameter values from a stack frame in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75076) suggests writing your own debugger or profiler, and links to the open-source [Mdbg](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2791459).